# What can you craft?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

I played through episode one and was able to craft a stone sword, slime block, bow and arrows.  When re-playing the episode I also found that I could craft a lever using cobblestone and a stick.

What can you craft in the game?

Comment: You asked too much questions about playing the "Story Mode" of Minecraft. There's only one question asked by someone else, and the total of questions asked about Minecraft Story Mode is about 5.

Comment: @Jim - not sure that is relevant.  I played the game as soon as it was released, so was asking about certain mechanics in the game otherwise not known to many. No other questions existed, and I could not find the answers elsewhere.

Comment: @Jim There is nothing wrong with asking several questions about the same game, as long as they're all good questions.

Comment: I know, it's just that I don't know why he has so much to ask.

Comment: There are actual hidden Easter eggs in the game, some related to getting items out of context and crafting with them. ATM I'm not at a computer so I can't easily look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following items on the Episodes are crafted:

## Episode 1

- Lever [Optional]
- Stone Sword
- Slime block
- Bow and arrow, or fishing rod.

## Episode 2

- Repeater [Optional]

## Episode 3

- Formidi-Bomb

## Episode 4

- Sticky Piston
- Redstone Block
- Lever
- Any Diamond Tool

Appearently, you can't craft other stuff since the fact that:

- You lack the materials for other stuff.
- The stuff not important for the game won't be crafted, even though the ingredients and the way of putting on the crafting table is correct.

In Episode 1, where you have to craft a stone sword, if you choose to make a lever, Petra will say it isn' useful for battle and you're back in the crafting table with more sticks and cobblestone. You'll get a [achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a208406/leveraging-resources-achievement.htm) for this. In the part where a dispenser trap is activated, you get the choice of a bow and arrow, or the fishing rod. Nothing really matters about the way you craft stuff. By the way I chose the bow and arrow since I didn't know you can also craft the fishing rod. In Episode 2 If you choosed to go get Ellegard you need to find a repeater. Either you craft one or [steal it from a disco guy by talking to him and the school boy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCi0_uepOp8). In Episode the Formidi-Bomb isn't really possible to craft in the normal Minecraft game, so you won't know you make it.  But as Soren told Jesse:

> "Remember, Super TNT in the middle, gunpower around it!"

It's possible to craft the Formidi-Bomb in Minecraft Story Mode. With the execption of the other episodes [I didn't metion about them because they aren't released], those are the only things you can craft in Minecraft Story Mode. Good luck saving the world from destruction!

Answer (score 4):

In Episode 1, there are three crafting puzzles. The materials you get are deliberately limited so there aren't many options.

In the first puzzle, you are supposed to make a sword. As you said, you can also make a lever. Petra will comment on how a lever won't be much good for defending yourself and let you take the materials for another sword. You will receive an achievement for this.

The second puzzle only allows you to make a slime block. You don't have enough string to make a lead so the slime block is your only option.

The third puzzle has two solutions. The bow and arrow is the obvious solution. You can also make a fishing rod, which will still solve the puzzle.

Comment: I chosed the bow and arrow for the part when you have to cross the arrow trap in the Temple of the Order of the Stone.

Comment: Why didn't you mention the other episodes? Oh it was because they weren't released!